# Flask Url with Prefix

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask App, which will run later as a "subpart" of a server and I am unsure how to configure that.

As an example:
`localhost/OtherServer/rest/myFlask/`

OtherServer is an IIS Website which normally handles all my requests, but for certain requsts control is handed to Flask - e.g. all routes which are found unter myFlask/*.

This already works thanks to WFASTCGI and some config magic, but in Flask I have to supply to the full URL for each route:
`@app.route('/OtherServer/rest/myFlask/status')`

I would like to only specify the part including or after myFlask, particularly because the firt part of the url is configurable in a C#-app and getting the name at runtime is a major headache.
So:

```
@app.route('/myFlask/status')
```

Comment: @rmn I have seen that post, but I am unable to get the APPLICATION_ROOT to work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use [blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/blueprints), use the `url_prefix` parameter.

---

I'll show you a simple example:

`view.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__, template_folder='templates', 
                         url_prefix='/OtherServer/rest')


@my_blueprint.route('/myFlask/status')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world.'

...other routes...
```

in your `app.py`, you can

```
from flask import Flask

from my_app.view import my_blueprint


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a good idea!